# Where was Mao Zedong during the Japanese surrender in Zhijiang (芷江) at the end of WWII in 1945?

Tags: world-war-two, china, ww2-pacific-theater, mao-zedong

Timeline for context:

- 9 August, 1945: [atomic bomb on Nagasaki](https://www.history.com/topics/world-war-ii/bombing-of-hiroshima-and-nagasaki).
- 15 August: the Japanese announced their acceptance of the unconditional surrender ([Potsdam Proclamation](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Potsdam-Declaration)).
- [21-23 August](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%8A%B7%E6%B1%9F%E5%8F%97%E9%99%8D/1745080?fr=aladdin): the Japanese surrender to the Chinese in the city of Zhijiang (芷江) in Hunan province (湖南省), China.  There's [videos of this surrender on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIAd4_FkCxo).
- 28 August to 10 October: Chiang Kai-shek and Mao Zedong were in Chongqing (重庆) in Sichuan province (四川省) in a [post-war peace negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Civil_War#Immediate_post-war_clashes_(1945%E2%80%931946)).
- 2 September: [the Japanese surrendered aboard the USS Missouri](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/world-war-ii/surrender-of-japan-aboard-missouri.html).

During WWII, I understand there was a "coalition government" between the Nationalist Party and Communist Party, so I'm curious as to where Mao Zedong was during the surrender in Zhijiang, and in particular, if he was in attendance.

**Question**: Where was Mao Zedong during the Japanese surrender in Zhijiang?

Prior to all this, on June 19, Mao Zedong was in Yan'an (延安) in Shaanxi province (陕西省) for the [7th Central Committee of the Communist Party of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7th_Central_Committee_of_the_Communist_Party_of_China).

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but the CCP and Kuomintang had been fighting each other since 1942; iow while simultaneously fighting the Japanese. The 'coalition' was a temporary truce which lasted for almost no time at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your assumption that "whole" JIA army surrendered on one day on 21-23 Aug, in Zhiijiang is nor correct.

It was **9th Sep** when Chinese Nationalist Party accepted the surrender of Japanese forces in Nanking according to [**this site.**](http://j.people.com.cn/n/2014/0901/c94474-8776875.html).

It was on 22th Sep that JIA forces surrendered in Zheng Prefecture.

There are many leaflets by the Chinese communist party congratulating the victory over the JIA forces from [**here.**](http://j.people.com.cn/94474/310248/index.html)

So the surrender was conducted by unit by unit ( or army group by army group ) independently by Chinese Nationalist Party or Communist Chinese.

Then or therefore it would be probably very hard for even Chinese native speakers to **pinpoint** where Mazo is **exactly at** when Japanese forces accepted the Potsdam Declaration (or else on 2 Sep, which is the "official" surrender day).

As you say, on 28th Aug, Mao Zedong and Chiang Kai-Shek held a party to congratulate the victory against Japanese Imperial forces at Chongqing.

[image]

So he might'be been anywhere, in Yan'an or moving to Chongqing, but I bet no one could know until someone gets a daily diary by Mao if such a thing exists.

Comment: Huh.  It seems there was a lot of these.  Wuhan also has [such a museum](http://www.mafengwo.cn/i/2965119.html).

Comment: What is this daily diary you speak of?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz ? I also don't know what it is. Mao may have written the war diary during the Sino-Japanese war or may have not. So who knows.

Comment: Is such a diary said to exsist?Is there any proof (even a faint one) behind it's exsistence?

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz I am concluding "So he might'be been anywhere, in Yan'an or moving to Chongqing, but I bet no one could know until someone gets the daily diary by Mao."

Comment: @SchwarzKugelblitz Sorry the way I concluded may have invited the misunderstanding. I edited.

Comment: I think documentation of Mao's daily movements exists. I'd be very surprised if it did not.

Comment: @axsvl77 Then please make your own answer by the document you mention....

Comment: @Kentaro I don't know what it is called, I don't read Chinese. BTW, this is a great answer.

Comment: @axsvl77 Thank you. But as far as I investigated, Mao in his life never celebrated the victory over the JIA officially, only on 2th Sep in 1951 he sent a message to Stalin saying "After 6th years from the victory against JIA, I would like to send you a congratulation message celebrating the Soviet army and Soviet people representing the People's Liberation Army". For FYI.